# Python input multiple lines and spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to solve one of the a2oj problems "**given three numbers a , b and c. print the total sum of the three numbers added to itself.**"

I came with this

```
import sys

numbers = [int(x) for x in sys.stdin.read().split()]

print(numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2])
```

I saw many topics but I cant figure out how to read just 3 values from input. I know I can stop this procces by typing CTRL+D, but is there any possibility to make it automatic (after reaching third value)?

Thanks

// Thanks for very quick answers, I made mistake and posted only Problem Statement without Input Format: **"three numbers separated by bunch of spaces and/or new lines"**

So for example input should look like this:

```
2                  

1                  4
```

// Ok thanks to you guys finally I made this:

```
n = []

while len(n) < 3:
    s=input()
    i = s.split()       
    [n.append(int(j)) for j in i]

print(2 * sum(n))
```

It's working but when I sent my results I got **Runtime Error**. I have no idea why:
Link: https://a2oj.com/p?ID=346

Answer (score 0):

You could just use:

sys.argv

```
  import sys
  numbers = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:4]]
  print(numbers)
  print(sum(numbers))
```

Comment: Thanks for very quick answers, I made mistake and posted only Problem Statement without Input Format: "three numbers separated by bunch of spaces and/or new lines"

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the update from the question author and linked the online judge question [description](https://a2oj.com/p?ID=346), the tweak to his code needed is below. It's worth noting that the expected output is in `float` and has precision set to `6` and the output is `2 * sum of all inputs`, not just `sum`. There is no description on this in the online judge question and you've to understand from the `input` vs `output`.

```py
n = []

while len(n) < 3:
    s = input()
    i = s.split()
    n.extend(float(j) for j in i)

print(format(2 * sum(n), '.6f'))
```

Screenshot below

[image: working solution]

But the first version of this answer is still valid to the first version of this question. Keeping them if anyone else is looking for the following scenarios.

To separate inputs by `enter` aka **New lines**:

```
numbers_List = []

for i in range(3):
    number = int(input())
    numbers_List.append(number)

print("Sum of all numbers: ", sum(numbers_List))
```

Screenshot:

[image: inputs seperated by enter]

To separate inputs by `space` aka **Bunch of spaces**:

Use `map` before taking input. I'd suggest using `input` as well instead of `sys.stdin.read()` to get input from users, separated by `space`, and ended by pressing `Enter` key.

Very easy implementation below for any number of inputs and to add using `sum` function on a list:

```py
numbers = list(map(int, input("Numbers: ").split())) 
print("Sum of all numbers: ", sum(numbers))
```

The screenshot below and link to the program is [here](https://repl.it/repls/ShoddyStormyParser)

[image: add all inputs seperated by space]

Read Python's [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) documentation to know more about all the functions I used above.

Comment: Thanks for very quick answers, I made mistake and posted only Problem Statement without Input Format: "three numbers separated by bunch of spaces and/or new lines"

Comment: Please don't copy/paste your response. Have you tried my code? Three or any numbers can be seperated by any number of spaces

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't work but thanks for try, I tried all of answer that people gave me, and all of it doesn't work. Im not asking only about spaces as I said "three numbers separated by bunch of SPACES and/or NEW LINES"

Comment: I just updated the code and provided examples for both scenarios you wanted

Comment: Thanks again, I tried but it still doesn't work in my scenario. Because I want to be able to give any number of spaces and enter. For example input:
`2                  

1                  4`

(few new lines between 2 and 1, and 1 is in SAME line with 4)
check my post I will edit it

Comment: Added the new answer, hope you don't get  any `Runtime error` anymore

Answer (score 0):

<s>I am not sure what you are looking for, but it seems that you are looking for is the input function, from python's builtins:</s>

```
x=input()
```

This reads any input from the user, as a string. You have then to convert it to a number if needed.

You can read three values:

```
x=input("First value:")
y=input("Second value:")
z=input("Third value:")
```

As you have now specified more precisely the problem statement, I edit my answer:

In your case, this is not very complicated. I am not going to give you the answer straight away, as it would defeat the point, but the idea is to wrap the input inside a while loop. Something like:

```
numbers=[]
while (you have less than 3 numbers):
    (input one line and add the numbers to your list)
(print the sum of your numbers)
```

That way you are waiting for as many inputs as you need until you reach 3 numbers. By the way, depending on your input, you might have to check whether you do not get more than 3 numbers.

Comment: Thanks for very quick answers, I made mistake and posted only Problem Statement without Input Format: "three numbers separated by bunch of spaces and/or new lines"

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer, implemented it and tested it on your input and it does work.

Comment: Hey thanks so much,
Reffering to your edit, I made this: 
`n = []

while len(n) < 3:
    s=input()
    i = s.split()       
    [n.append(int(j)) for j in i]

print(2 * sum(n))
`
Its actually working! But when I sent my results on website, I recieved "Runtime Error" do you know why is that? (Link to problem: https://a2oj.com/p?ID=346)

Comment: Hi,
It took me some time to figure it out, actually the numbers in the input are not only integers but any kind of number. So you just need to change "int(j)" to "int(i)". However, I would not advise using this line:
    `[n.append(int(j)) for j in i]`
I would advise using the extend method:
    `n.extend(float(j) for j in i)`
I checked it and it is now accepted, the converting of a float string into an integer was raising a ValueError, which is a subclass of RuntimeError.

Answer (score 0):

1. When inputs are given line by line.

```
from sys import stdin
sum = 0
for num in stdin.readline(4):
    sum = sum + int(num)
print(sum)
```

2. When inputs are given on CLI.

```
from sys import argv
sum = 0
for num in argv[1:4]:
    sum = sum + int(num)
print(sum)
```

Use Python `strip()` and `split()` functions as per your usecases